# get when active directory was last backed up

Tags: c#, active-directory

Does any one knows how we can find

When active directory was last backed up using C#?

according to my knowledge when we run this command
repadmin /showbackup

its will shows us full detail. I tried to get value of dsa signature using C#, but even that value does not make much sense, and will help us to get correct information of.

Like from which domain controller backup was initiated and on when?

Anyone knows how to get this last backup detail of active directory using C#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any cmd line commands you can run to garner this information?

Answer (score 0):

I have found many times that not all may be done with WMI, The below code should run the requisite command to show the information you requested and then redirect it to standard out.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo PSI =
new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "Repadmin.exe /showbackup");

PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;

PSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = PSI;
proc.Start();
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(result);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
      Messagebox.Show(e.InnerException);
      }
}
```

Comment: thanks thats the only way even i am thinking to do this. But there is another problem to do this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598141/run-active-directory-shell-commands-using-c-sharp here